# Accessing Location on Windows 10 in .net desktop application

Tags: vb.net, gps, location, windows-10-desktop

The company I work for has an application used by our field staff that registers their GPS location periodically, we initially wrote the application for windows 8 x86 using the System.Device.Location GeoCoordinateWatcher class.

In windows 10 the same code ceases to function properly, the GeoCoordinateWatcher.Permission returns Granted, yet we continue to receive an unknown position each call.  The windows 8 and windows 10 tablets both have LTE.

```
    Public Function GetLocation() As GeoCoordinate
         Dim geoCoordinate As GeoCoordinate
         Dim watcher As GeoCoordinateWatcher
         watcher = New GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
         watcher.TryStart(False, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000))

         LogToFile("Position Permission: " & watcher.Permission.ToString)
         LogToFile("Watcher Status: " & watcher.Status.ToString)

         geoCoordinate = watcher.Position.Location

         If geoCoordinate.IsUnknown Then
             LogToFile("Unknown")
         Else
             LogToFile(String.Format("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}, H Accuracy: {2}, V Accuracy: {3}, Crse: {4}, Spd: {5}, Alt: {6}", geoCoordinate.Latitude, geoCoordinate.Longitude, geoCoordinate.HorizontalAccuracy, geoCoordinate.VerticalAccuracy, geoCoordinate.Course, geoCoordinate.Speed, geoCoordinate.Altitude))

         End If
         Return geoCoordinate
     End Function
```

Our log file shows every call we have permission granted, a mix of status = NoData or Initializing, and the position is always unknown.

We do get a notification on the tablets that an application is accessing location information, and I can confirm the GPS is indeed working as the built in maps application correctly shows the current GPS location.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else to try to troubleshoot what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your function I would assume you do not have a handler that actual get's called when the position changes. This event is `PositionChanged Event` [**(please see here)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.positionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), this is fired when the latitude or longitude of the location data has changed.

I would recommend changing your declaration of `watcher` to a class level variable and also making it `WithEvents`. For example...

```
 Private WithEvents watcher As GeoCoordinateWatcher
```

Now you have access to all of the other methods and functions for this class. Your event that would be the callback for the position changes would look something like this.

```
Private Sub watcher_PositionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GeoPositionChangedEventArgs(Of GeoCoordinate))
   'here you have access to latitude and longitude coordinates for example...
  'e.Position.Location.Altitude etc...   
End Sub
```

So all wrapped up ....

```
 Private WithEvents watcher As GeoCoordinateWatcher'declare outside of function....

 Public Sub StartLocation()
         watcher = New GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
         AddHandler watcher.PositionChanged, AddressOf watcher_PositionChanged
         watcher.Start(False, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000))
 End Sub

 Private Sub watcher_PositionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GeoPositionChangedEventArgs(Of GeoCoordinate))
       LogToFile("Position Permission: " & watcher.Permission.ToString)
       LogToFile("Watcher Status: " & watcher.Status.ToString)

      e.* 'whatever you need here...
 End Sub
```

Comment: You are indeed correct, we originally had PositionChanged in our original windows 8 program, but after a fair amount of in the field testing found starting the watcher and reading once was far more reliable in that situation than starting and catching position changed events.  I'll give that a shot though, as the new OS change may have thrown that balance off the other direction.